# Kurento Installation Unmet Dependencies

Tags: kurento

I am trying to install latest stable version of Kurento (V 6.0) in Ubutu Trusty (14.04). Unfortunately, I've got stranger messages:

Output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
kurento-media-server-6.0 : Depends: kms-core-6.0 (>= 6.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.41.1) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                        Depends: libgstreamer1.5-0 (>= 1.7.1.1~20160224213114.199.gba35ee7.trusty) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gstreamer1.5-plugins-base (>= 1.7.0~0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gstreamer1.5-libav (>= 1.7.0~0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gstreamer1.5-plugins-bad (>= 1.7.0~0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gstreamer1.5-plugins-good (>= 1.7.0~0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gstreamer1.5-plugins-ugly (>= 1.7.0~0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: kms-elements-6.0 (>= 6.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: kms-filters-6.0 (>= 6.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Input:

```
echo "deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org trusty kms6" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kurento.list
wget -O - http://ubuntu.kurento.org/kurento.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0
```

I guess there are some problem was happened with libglib2.0-0 and libgstreamer1.5-0 but I do not know how to solve it.

I've got instance of Kurento 5.x 8 months ago within a success of installation in Trusty, but now I have to update to 6.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ve got solution

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install kurento-media-server-6.0
```

It works for me

Comment: Have same problem but aptitude did not helped sadly.

Comment: At end i downgraded to ubuntu to 14.4 , that was problem.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is @hoanganh17b solution

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install kurento-media-server-6.0
```

then when asked ***Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]***, instead of keying **Y**, do this:

```
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] +
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
```

scroll until you reach the line that has ***libglib2.0-0***, in my case it's 22 and 23. That line will look like this:

```
Upgrade the following packages:        

22)     libglib2.0-0 [2.42.2-0ubuntu1~14.04~ricotz0 (now, trusty) -> 2.46.1-1 (<NULL>)]  
23)     libglib2.0-bin [2.42.2-0ubuntu1~14.04~ricotz0 (now, trusty) -> 2.46.1-1 (<NULL>)]
```

then key in the ff. answers on the ***Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]*** portion:

```
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] 22
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] a 22


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] 23
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] a 23
```

The kurento-media-server-6.0 will then be installed.

To test and confirm it's installed:

```
sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 start
sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 stop
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your ubuntu version is 14.04 **LTS 64bit**
base on Kurento installation guid:
*[Kurento Media Server (KMS) has to be installed on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 bits).](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation_guide.html)*