# Kurento Media Server Installation on Ubuntu 14.04 /15.04 gives unmet dependency error

Tags: ubuntu, kurento

I am installing Kurento Media Server 6.0 on my ubuntu machine 14.04. I am following this link 
https://www.kurento.org/docs/6.0.0/installation_guide.html

Java installed on my machine is java 8

```
abhimanyu@abhimanyu:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

I am getting dependencies issue on my machine , even

```
sudo apt-get update
```

run successfully on my machine , once I added the repository to kurento.list

```
abhimanyu@abhimanyu:~$ sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kurento-media-server-6.0 : Depends: kms-core-6.0 (>= 6.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gstreamer1.5-plugins-good (>= 1.7.0~0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: kms-elements-6.0 (>= 6.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: kms-filters-6.0 (>= 6.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Since repository is added and ubuntu is successfully updated. It shouldn't give any dependency issue while installation.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: I have done the dist-upgrade but still I am getting the same error

Comment: I have explicitly installed sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0
and then after that kurento installed fine using command sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0

Comment: I had the same issue and documented what worked for me to solve this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979413/kurento-installation-unmet-dependencies/38216884#38216884